# driver canon MG6200

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am trying to install the canon MG6200 driver hoping that i can print double sided after that. I have extracted the tarball and ran the install.sh file. This gives me this output:

root@user-Lenovo-B575e:/home/user/Downloads# cd ./cnijfilter-mg6200series-3.60-1-rpm

## root@user-Lenovo-B575e:/home/user/Downloads/cnijfilter-mg6200series-3.60-1-rpm# ./install.sh

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver
Version 3.60
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2011
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location.
root@user-Lenovo-B575e:/home/user/Downloads/cnijfilter-mg6200series-3.60-1-rpm#

Any ideas how to solve this would be immensly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the "rpm" part in  : "cnijfilter-mg6200series-3.60-1-***rpm***", even  know a script it could only work for RedHat and other rpm distros.

There is a much more easy and better way to get your printer working.

Go to `system settings` by opening dash (that thing in the upper left with the Ubuntu logo) and then  type and click on *system settings* and the  click the *printers* menu. You will be guided by  a wizard.

I looked it up for you and your printer is in the database.

Comment: Oh great. I didnt know that was a possibility. Ill try that when i get Home. Thanks for your help